# Open shift internal docker registry's virtual IP lost connection with all the masters and nodes

Tags: openshift, devops

As a result getting image pull error while submitting the deployment to the kube API. Even the docker registry pod IP is in connection but VIRTUAL IP of docker registry lost connection with the cluster.

Observed these logs in server.
Error response from daemon: Get http://VIRTUAL IP:5000: dial tcp VIRTUAL IP:5000: connect: no route to host
All the 5000 no. port is free across all the nodes and master.

Docker registry lies in different project that is default. Previously, it was connected properly, the disconnection happened suddenly.

**Epitome of the issue**: Docker registry virtual IP lost connection with the entire openshift cluster. So, is there a possible way that we can re-establish the connection between the docker registry's virtual IP and openshift cluster?

Docker registry POD is in different project(namespace) within the cluster.

Comment: Can I know which OpenShift version you are using. From OpenShift 4.0 we get the URL for pulling and pushing the images,

Comment: Open shift 3.7 version

Comment: That happened suddenly. Previously it was able to pull and I was able to reach that VIRTUAL IP from all the nodes within the cluster.